# Is it possible to use crypt command of unix without user prompt for key

Tags: unix

I want to use crypt command for encrypting a file, but the key I want to keep fixed and not give a user prompt for entering a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crypt key < file.txt > file1.txt

Comment: I guess you don't care that the key is not stored securely.

Comment: I do...I'm looking into that now of generating key based on some algorithm or random.Share some insight if u have